# Undeclared Identifier error using simple macro C++

Tags: c++

Check this out:

```
#include <iostream>  //input outut like cout, cin
#include <string>  //strings
#include <cstdlib>  //includes random num generators and basic c++ functions 
#include <limits> //functions for min and max for data types 
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> //sequences of values
#include <cmath> //math functions
#include <sstream> //string stream
#include <ctime> //time
#include <algorithm> //includes sort
#include <fstream>  //alllows ofstream and ifstream for some reason? unicode vs ansi? 
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include <functional>  //allows you to use function poitner? <function>   

#define PI 3.14159 //anywhere you see PI, it will be replaced with the number to its right 
    #define AREA_CIRC (radius) (PI * pow(radius, 2))

    int main(){

    cout << "Circle Area " << AREA_CIRC(5) << endl;

    }
```

Whenever I run this code, it gives me this error:

> Error C2065 'radius': undeclared identifier   Derektut

**Why?** 
declaring int radius in the macro definition makes no difference

Comment: Remove the "int" in the definition of AREA_CIRC.

Comment: @wychmaster doing that gives the same error

Comment: While posting future questions, also include the headers. Don't know if you also included the required ones or not

Comment: @skrrrt I've edited it to include my header files, thanks for the tip

Comment: [Same error ?](https://godbolt.org/z/v7cN9F)

Comment: @wychmaster I actually added the int radius there when it didn't work with just having radius

Comment: @skrrrt it appears it was a spacing error. Thanks for the link btw, I now know to use online compilers to test simple concepts instead of opening another instance of VS 2019 like i have lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#define AREA_CIRC (radius) (PI * pow(radius, 2))` means

> replace all `AREA_CIRC` with `(radius) (PI * pow(radius, 2))`

As a result, you just get plain text substitution including `radius` which really is an unknown identifier. What you probably meant was a function-like macro:

`#define AREA_CIRC(radius) (PI * pow(radius, 2))`

Just remove the space between the macro name and its opening bracket.

Comment: Yes this is the correct answer. This is also a reason why preprocessor directives are usually a bad idea, especially when more parameters and multi line functionality is needed.

Comment: @passing_through thanks that did the trick. First time using macros, I didn't know spacing meant that much? Why would spacing matter in this situation?

Comment: @edo101  there are cases when you want something like `#define FOO (value)` (replacing all `FOO`s with `(value)`) and when you want `#define FOO(value) value + 1` (replacing all `FOO(bar)`s with `bar + 1`) so C/C++ allow both variants.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro expands as

```
cout << "Circle Area " << (radius) (PI * pow(radius, 2))(5) << endl;
```

not the way you expected. @passing_through gave you the cure.

Answer (score 2):

The below was mostly written before you made your edit, so I will suggest removing the space between `AREA_CIRC` and `(radius)` and see if that helps (it worked for me).

Worth noting that the rest still mostly applies, except maybe the part which suggested getting rid of the type declaration.

---

Macros don't use type declarations. They are pure text substitutions (which makes them somewhat unsafe to use). Thus, `int` here is unnecessary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define PI 3.14159 //anywhere you see PI, it will be replaced with the number to its right 
#define AREA_CIRC(radius) (PI * pow(radius, 2))

int main(){

cout << "Circle Area " << AREA_CIRC(5) << endl;

}
```

[That should work](https://onlinegdb.com/Skb3IxNFI), though especially if you're using macros, [I don't recommend using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10957435) even though I've used it here quickly to create an example.

Ultimately, it'd be better to use a `constexpr` function instead:

```
constexpr float AREA_CIRC (int radius) { // double will work here as well, if desired
    return (PI * pow(radius, 2));
}
```

---

Also, excellent suggestion by @passing_through, you can also change `PI` to a `constexpr` as well:

```
constexpr double PI = 3.14159;
```

Comment: Thank you! have a lot to learn. why don't you recommend namespace std. It makes typing eaiser @Chipster

Comment: The link connected explained that far better than I could. The gist of it is this could lead to naming conflicts that are hard to find and debug.

Comment: @edo101 It the goal of programming languages to make it possible to write good quaility code, not to make typing easier.

Comment: You can also advise to change `PI` to a `constexpr double pi`.

Comment: @passing_through great suggestion. I've added it.